# 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, demosaicing

Running this script:

```
import time
import picamera
import picamera.array
import numpy as np

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    with picamera.array.PiBayerArray(camera) as stream:
        camera.capture(stream, 'jpeg', bayer=True)
        # Demosaic data and write to output (just use stream.array if you
        # want to skip the demosaic step)
        output = (stream.array() >> 2).astype(np.uint8)
        with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            output.tofile(f)
```

Gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numpy_simple.py", line 11, in <module>
    output = (stream.array() >> 2).astype(np.uint8)
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

While running:

```
output = (stream.demosaic() >> 2).astype(np.uint8)
        with open('image.data', 'wb') as f:
            output.tofile(f)
```

Does not give any error.

I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array` is an attribute, not a method.  You don't need to call it.

Use `stream.array`, not `stream.array()`.

Source: [`PiArrayOutput`](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/blob/6f36295e3ecd7543f633d3770bc7ef08840e3611/picamera/array.py#L180), which is the base class for `PiBayerArray`.

Conversely, [`.demosaic()`](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/blob/6f36295e3ecd7543f633d3770bc7ef08840e3611/picamera/array.py#L439) is an instance method, which is why you need to call it to get its return value.